# Cannot replace a specific part of string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I've some problem with a string replace, in particular I've a php that return an array, each index of array contains a specific string of translation. So essentially, this array are saved inside: `GlobalVariables.language['hello_world']`, that for example return `Hello world`.

Now I've an array index that contains this translation string:

```
wait $seconds seconds before try again
```

I set the seconds inside an interval function that working as a countdown:

```
setInterval(function ()
    {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        text = text.replace('$seconds', seconds);
        console.log(text);

        $('.alert').text(text);

        if (--timer < 0)
        {
            timer = 0; //Stoppo il timer
        }
    }, 1000);
```

this will return a string like this:

```
wait 20 seconds before try again
```

but only for the first time, 'cause later the $seconds part of the string is already replaced, I though to replace only digital number of text for second timing, but I can't do this 'cause before call setInterval I append the string to another that contains a digital number.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `text = text.replace(/\$seconds|\d+/, seconds);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dont replace the original variable but use a different one.

`text` will then always contain `$seconds`:-

```js
setInterval(function() {
  minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
  seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

  minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
  seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

  var text2 = text.replace('$seconds', seconds);
  console.log(text2);

  $('.alert').text(text2);

  if (--timer < 0) {
    timer = 0; //Stoppo il timer
  }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

First time it works as `$seconds` is found in the string. However next time(2nd iteration onward) since `$seconds` not exists in the `text`, thus its not replaced.

You should persist original with element and used it as template.

```
//Perists original text with element
var alertElem = $('.alert');
alertElem.data('text', text);

setInterval(function (){
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    alertElem.text(function(){
        return alertElem.data('text').replace('$seconds', seconds)
    });

    if (--timer < 0)
    {
        timer = 0; 
    }
}, 1000);
```